# Jena java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with execConstruct

Tags: jena, concurrentmodification

executing the following code:

```
     Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);      
     QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);          
     Model m = qexec.execConstruct(model);     
     System.out.println(m.toString());
     model.close();
```

sometimes arises the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException exeception, depending on the type of query I'm executing. There is a way to build an always-safe snippet of code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Model m = qexec.execConstruct()` (no model argument) then call `model.add(m)`.

If you query and insert statements on the same model, via `execConstruct(model)`) there is a risk of CCME.  Using a different model for the results avoids that.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but I was wandering if there is a clean way to avoid CCME with execConstruct(model).

Comment: There isn't. The use case for execConstruct(model) is for a different model but because models can be composed of other models, detecting if the query model is involved in the execConstruct(model) is challenging.